# declaring a function pointer of a templatized instance object

Tags: c++, templates

Have seen numerous examples of having templatized function pointers. An example is here [template and typedef](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm). I couldn't find any example where the function pointer is for a class instance which is a template class. For example

```
namespace xyz{
    template <class T>  
    class TemplateClass{
        typedef std::string (*ParameterlessFunctionPointer)();
    }
}
```

How do I define the instance of `ParameterlessFunctionPointer` in a different class?

Comment: What's the problem? [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abbabd3fd74780b1) an obvious use of the `typedef` which compiles fine. And it looks like the uses mentioned in the linked GOTW article. An example from there is `Registry<Employee>::Type employeeRoster;`.

Comment: my function pointer is declared in a different class. Can this declaration make use of template as well? Otherwise I need to declare function pointers of all possible types which defeats the use of templates.

Answer (score 0):

If it was meant to be defined in multiple classes, then the typedef should be declared outside the scope of the template class, and just in xyz. A typedef is really only put inside a class if that class is the only user of the typedef.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string foo()
{
   return "foo";
}
```

Since `ParameterlessFunctionPointer` doesn't depend on the template parameter, you can use:

```
xyz::TemplateClass<int>::ParameterlessFunctionPointer ptr1 = &foo;
xyz::TemplateClass<double>::ParameterlessFunctionPointer ptr2 = &foo;
```

Comment: so that I means I need to create function pointer objects of all possible types of template classes? I cannot use template for this purpose? Defeats the purpose of templates for me.

Comment: @Alok, it's not clear to me what you were hoping to get from having the `typedef` in the class template.

Comment: that is because we cannot have a templated typedef. Only way to achieve this is to have typedef inside a template class. My issue was with `ParameterlessFunctionPointer`. I need to declare specific pointers for each type it supports. This cannot be templated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
xyz::TemplateClass<int>::ParameterlessFunctionPointer fn = &some;
```

Or if the other class is a template as well:

```
template <typename T>
struct OtherTemplateClass
{
    typename xyz::TemplateClass<T>::ParameterlessFunctionPointer fn_member;
};
```

To make it shorter you may use a typedef if needed...

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to do but it didn't work for me. Accessing a function pointer of templatized class generates syntax error.
`file.h:116: error: type 'xyz::TemplateClass<T>' is not derived from type 'xyz::ParameterlessFunctionPointer<T>'`

Comment: @Alok `ParameterlessFunctionPointer` is not a template, why do you try to instantiate it? (according your error message, it tried to be used as a template which is definitely incorrect)